# Are the only discrete groups with nontrivial p-adic Haar measure finite?

Tags: p-adic-groups

Let K be a complete non-archimedean field (say $\mathbb{C_p}$) and let G be a discrete group. Since {e} is an open p-compatible compact subgroup of G, G admits a (left) K-valued Haar measure $\mu$. Obviously $\mu(\{g\})=\mu(\{e\})$ for all $g\in G$. But now there is a canonical isometry of the space of (tight) measures M(G) and c<sub>0</sub>(G). Thus, the set of the points with $|\mu(\{x\})|\ge |\mu(\{e\})|$ must be compact. Thus, the only discrete groups with nontrivial Haar measure are finite. What am I (possibly) doing wrong.

Comment: What is a tight measure? How is the isometry between $M(G)$ and $c_0(G)$? Usually $c_0(G)' = M(G)$, so there is a dual. I can't actually see why it should matter $C_p$ or $C$ valued measures here. It is more likely to see where you go wrong if you add all definitions.

Comment: @plusepsilon.de I think You have answered my question by pointing out that I was not attentive enough while reading the books. Thank You.

Comment: $\{e\}$ is NOT open. The open subgroups are not compact unless the field is locally compact; even then $\{e\}$ is not open.

Comment: @Venkataramana Well, the question may have sounded a bit misleading, but the group was meant to be $discrete$ and not  kind of algebraic group over the abovementioned field. In a discrete group, each subset is open and closed. Moreover, if one wishes a $p$-adic Haar measure on a group, the group itself has to be $p$-$free$ (see van Rooij's classical book on the subject).

PS When I asked this question 2.5 years ago, I knew virtually nothing on the subject. And it's been a year since I've had to leave academia, so gradually I'm forgetting everything I've learned since then :(

Comment: @Kolya: sorry. I missed the point that the measure has values in $K$. But then the notion of measure is problematic: what is the definition of countable additivity? The sequence $1+1+1+\cdots$ does not converge but nor is it going to infinity: the sequence of partial sums has, as limit points $0,1,\cdots, n, ...$. But you may be asking only for finite additivity.

Comment: @Venkataramana Honeslty, it's been so long ago. My question back than came from a crucial misunderstanding of the nature of p-adic measures: an example misguided me to think that the measure is concentrated at points. I remember having a solution to my problem back then, some months after this question was asked, but the thing remains unpublished somewhere in the drafts.

Comment: @sorry: I saw this post recently and did not realize that this was an old post.